# Getting half values of dataset

Tags: r

My apologies in advance this is my first post.

I have the following dataset. I would like to get the time the vessels reach the half of their max speeds(such as vessel 1 6 sec., vessel 2 4 sec.) I have 20 different vessels to get their half-speed time value. Many thanks in advance.

```
vessel  time    speed 
vessel1 1   6
vessel1 2   7
vessel1 3   10
vessel1 4   16
vessel1 5   18
vessel1 6   20
vessel1 7   22
vessel1 8   24
vessel1 9   36
vessel1 10  37
vessel1 11  38
vessel1 12  38
vessel1 13  39
vessel1 14  40
vessel1 15  41
vessel1 16  41
vessel1 17  41
vessel2 1   7
vessel2 2   9
vessel2 3   12
vessel2 4   15
vessel2 5   20
vessel2 6   22
vessel2 7   23
vessel2 8   24
vessel2 9   25
vessel2 10  26
vessel2 11  27
vessel3 12  28
vessel4 13  29
vessel5 14  30
```

Comment: I think you'll be able to get help more effectively if you tweak your question. What have you tried to solve the problem? How is your data stored... is it already in a data frame or vector, or still in a CSV? What do both numbers represent?

Comment: Data is stored in csv. Time represents in seconds and speed is mph. I am trying to get the secs of each vehicle when they reach to half of their max speed.

Comment: What result you expect if there is only entry for the *vessel* (e.g. *vessel3*), please edit your question!  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47925537/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get example data:

```
df <- read.table(text="
vessel  time    speed 
vessel1 1   6
vessel1 2   7
vessel1 3   10
vessel1 4   16
vessel1 5   18
vessel1 6   20
vessel1 7   22
vessel1 8   24
vessel1 9   36
vessel1 10  37
vessel1 11  38
vessel1 12  38
vessel1 13  39
vessel1 14  40
vessel1 15  41
vessel1 16  41
vessel1 17  41
vessel2 1   7
vessel2 2   9
vessel2 3   12
vessel2 4   15
vessel2 5   20
vessel2 6   22
vessel2 7   23
vessel2 8   24
vessel2 9   25
vessel2 10  26
vessel2 11  27
vessel3 12  28
vessel4 13  29
vessel5 14  30"
,header = T)
```

Use a `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(vessel) %>%              # for each vessel
  filter(speed >= max(speed)/2) %>% # keep all speed values above or equal to the half of max speed
  filter(speed == min(speed)) %>%   # keep the minimum speed value
  ungroup()                         # forget the grouping

# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#    vessel  time speed
#    <fctr> <int> <int>
# 1 vessel1     7    22
# 2 vessel2     4    15
# 3 vessel3    12    28
# 4 vessel4    13    29
# 5 vessel5    14    30
```

Comment: What a great solution! Greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do it (replace read.table with read.csv("youfilename.csv"):

```
mydf <- read.table(text="
vessel1 1   6
vessel1 2   7
vessel1 3   10
vessel1 4   16
vessel1 5   18
vessel1 6   20
vessel1 7   22
vessel1 8   24
vessel1 9   36
vessel1 10  37
vessel1 11  38
vessel1 12  38
vessel1 13  39
vessel1 14  40
vessel1 15  41
vessel1 16  41
vessel1 17  41
vessel2 1   7
vessel2 2   9
vessel2 3   12
vessel2 4   15
vessel2 5   20
vessel2 6   22
vessel2 7   23
vessel2 8   24
vessel2 9   25
vessel2 10  26
vessel2 11  27
vessel3 12  28
vessel4 13  29
vessel5 14  30"
)

colnames(mydf) = c("Vessel","Time","Speed")

middle_Speed_Time = by(mydf,mydf[,"Vessel"],function(x){ min(x[x[,3] >= max(x[,3])/2,2]) } )
```

The first line reads in the data.

The second line just gives them standardised names for convenience.

The third line goes through the data.frame by each vessel and finds the first timepoint that the machine goes above half speed (i.e. >= max(speed)/2).

Comment: Brilliant!!! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
d <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"vessel  time    speed 
vessel1 1   6
vessel1 2   7
vessel1 3   10
vessel1 4   16
vessel1 5   18
vessel1 6   20
vessel1 7   22
vessel1 8   24
vessel1 9   36
vessel1 10  37
vessel1 11  38
vessel1 12  38
vessel1 13  39
vessel1 14  40
vessel1 15  41
vessel1 16  41
vessel1 17  41
vessel2 1   7
vessel2 2   9
vessel2 3   12
vessel2 4   15
vessel2 5   20
vessel2 6   22
vessel2 7   23
vessel2 8   24
vessel2 9   25
vessel2 10  26
vessel2 11  27
vessel3 12  28
vessel4 13  29
vessel5 14  30")

which.halfspeed <- function(speed) {
  half <- max(speed)/2
  sum(speed<=half)
}

index <- tapply(d$speed, d$vessel, which.halfspeed)
index
mapply('[', split(d$time, d$vessel), index)
```